Is there a sigma for unexplained hypothetical discoveries?
I recently read that the Koide formula relating electronic leptons rest masses is often considered to be numerologic, since unexplained, even though recent years experiment data tend to narrow the formula result to its expected value.
Is there or could there be a statistical approach to determine a sigma for this type of equations? Considering the Koide formula for instance, we could wonder, taken any 3 random values, what the probability is, for the formula to produce a result in a close range (here about $10^{-5}$) to a chosen integer fraction ? And maybe also consider that other fractions would also have raisen our attention: we’d be intrigued too if the formula result had been $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1}{3}$ or $\frac{3}{5}$ etc… Finally we would have to introduce the experiments uncertainties ranges as ponderation.
What value should such a sigma have for the considered formula to be “significant”?
